# Couldn't read row 34, col 11 from CursorWindow

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've got following error from some user.

Couldn't read row 34, col 11 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

This issue happende in follwoing line:

```
@Override
    public void bindView(final Context context, Cursor MessageCursor, int position) {

        final MessageEntity messageEntity = MessageDataSource.cursorToMessage(MessageCursor);

       // more code
     }
```

and `cursorToMessage` is:

```
public static MessageEntity cursorToMessage(Cursor cursor) {
        MessageEntity.Builder builder = new MessageEntity.Builder();
        builder.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessageTable.COLUMN_ID)))
                .setMessageId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessageTable.COLUMN_MESSAGE_ID)))
                .setJabberId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessageTable.COLUMN_JID)))
                .setContactUsername(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessageTable.COLUMN_CONTACT_USERNAME)))
                .setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessageTable.COLUMN_TEXT)))
                .setType(MessageEntity.Type.getEnum(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessageTable.COLUMN_TYPE))))
                .setTimestamp(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessageTable.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)))
                .setDeliveryStatus(MessageEntity.DeliveryStatus.getEnum(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessageTable.COLUMN_STATUS))))
                .setUnread((cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessageTable.COLUMN_UNREAD)) > 0))
                .setOutgoing((cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessageTable.COLUMN_OUTGOING)) > 0))
                .setThumbnail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessageTable.COLUMN_THUMBNAIL)))
                .setJsonData(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessageTable.COLUMN_EXTRA_DATA)));

        return builder.build();
    }
```

I've search a lot in SO but other problem is like Couldn't read row -1 or Couldn't read column -1 that it's caused when you don't call `moveToFirst()` or you don't have one column. as this problem happened for some user i can't detect why this happened. did you have any idea.

if you want more info or more code tell me. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

My `projection` is `null` and i have all columns. this problem not happened for all user.

**Update**

My problem is outOfMemory, as i catch that exception in one place in my project, application crashed in some where else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store large data in an Android SQLite database. The `CursorWindow` can only hold 2MB of data, any row larger than that will cause an error like this.

In particular, the `COLUMN_THUMBNAIL` seems to be the culprit. Instead of storing image data in the database, store images in the filesystem and just store the path in database.

For reference, the exception [gets thrown](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/jni/android_database_CursorWindow.cpp#48) whenever [`CursorWindow::getFieldSlot()`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/CursorWindow.cpp#257) returns `NULL`. Out-of-bounds indices are a common reason for that, but that isn't the case with you - both the row and column numbers are valid. Full cursor window is another reason.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i don't store image data, i just store one token for getting from internet or device.anyway, so how can handle large data? because this is a messaging application.

Comment: Doesn't need to be image data, just any data that makes a row over 2MB in size.

Comment: is there any other situation to happened this exception ? like access two thread on one data or something like this

Comment: Laalto i don't think so that this be my problem, because if cursor window be full i must get error like `Window is full: requested allocation 2195889 bytes, free space 2096720 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes`. am i right?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my problem is `outOfMemory`. but as your answer might be cause in most case i remain your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure you forgot to add the column to the projection or that you did not call `moveToFirst()` in the beginning.

Comment: Kevin as i said in my question this problem happened for some user ( 35 user of 300000 ). if i forgot the column i got error from all user. and when you forgot add one column you get couldn't read row x Column -1

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I would suggest not using getColumnIndexOrThrow, and break point and step over till it breaks.

Comment: please see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndexOrThrow%28java.lang.String%29.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan only step over entire function once. If it does not break than I haven't experienced something like that, where it throws that exception randomly on the cursor after awhile

Comment: Kevin I call this method in `bindView` in `CursorAdapter`. we don't need call `moveToFirst()`. and as i said in question if i don't call that i must get couldn't read row -1 column x.

Comment: Okay my apologizes didn't reliaze you are using a CursorLoader

Comment: thanks for your answer, i think laalto's answer is right, +1 for your time